# Two or more words in regular expression

Tags: c#, nsregularexpression

I have a problem with a regular expression in the next variable

```
[Required]
       [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+",         
ErrorMessage = "No numbers please")]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string name{ get; set; }
```

The problem is that in the html form it only accepts one word. I need the input to accept any number of words

I tried using the "+" plus the same regular expression but it doesn't work.

```
[Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1] + [a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]",
         ErrorMessage = "No numbers pleas")]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string name{ get; set; }
```

And also, the next code

```
[Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1] +",
         ErrorMessage = "No numbers pleas")]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string name{ get; set; }
```

But when I try to put "John Smith" it doesn't work. Could someone explain to me how to fix it

Comment: Spaces in a regular expression patter are important. `] +` is _very_ different than `]+`.

Comment: A word can't contain an apostrophe? Or a hyphen? If you're concerned about rejecting strings that contain digits, maybe make your pattern for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the blank space inside the brackets and you have an unwanted blank space before the '+' sign.
You can try any of the next expressions

```
[RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1 ]+")]
```

Or simply

```
[RegularExpression(@"[\w ]+")] //Don't forget the white space
```

*\w* matches any word character.

You can also add *\s* which matches any invisible character. But the space should do the trick.